# Make the LEFT part of the site scroll down automatically with the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, scroll, fixed

I would like to make the same scrolling feature for my "left" part of the website the same as on this website ( http://compassionateessentials.com/ ). It's not just putted as a position: fixed; ... it becomes "fixed" only when it has about 50px from top.

Comment: Exactly as you said. :) Make it fixed when you scroll right amount of pixels. You can also make a more "dynamic" solution with jQuery by checking and setting top position when scrolling (for example with http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/jquery-sticky-scroller-position-fixed-plugin/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since so many people have been asking me how I did that on that particular site - I wrote a blog post over at [here](http://threefifty.ca/blog/2012/03/21/fixed-menu-using-jquery). If anyone has any more questions, don't hesitate to ask in the comments!